# RX+Retrofit filtring data from server Response

Tags: android, function, filter, retrofit, rx-java2

**how to use RxJava Function .filter()** for particular condition, i want
just only data which id is  168 ,
is this right way to do or have to change my code style give me your valuable suggestion. (Without RetroLambda use :))

```
 NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest(this);
 RestApi api = networkRequest.getInstance().create(RestApi.class);

    subscription = api
            .school()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<SchoolList>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted: completed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError: on Error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<SchoolList> schoolResponse) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "onNext: " + schoolResponse.getSchoolList().size());
                }
            });
```

> i have response like

```
{ "schoolList": [
 {
  "name": "A University",

    "id": "168"
 },
 {
  "name": "Alba Sciences",
  "id": "271"
 },
 {
  "name": "B University",

    "id": "168"
 }]
}
```

> i have try this way but getting noting in  (On Next)

```
 NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest(this);
 RestApi api = networkRequest.getInstance().create(RestApi.class);

    subscription = api
            .school()
            .filter(new Func1<Response<SchoolList>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Response<SchoolList> schoolListResponse) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "condition: computing 2");
                    return schoolListResponse.getSchoolList().get(0).getId().equals("168");
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<SchoolList>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted: completed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError: on Error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<SchoolList> schoolResponse) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "onNext: " + schoolResponse.getSchoolList().size());
                }
            });
```

Comment: check out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40887006/3629732)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to use something like following (strongly recommend using RetroLambda (or Jack when it's ready) when using RxJava)

```
    api.school()
            .flatMapIterable(schoolResponse -> schoolResponse.getSchoolList())
            .filter(school -> school.getId().equals("168"))
            .toList()
```

Comment: Thanx Johan for your quick response , yeah i have read about that , just working on RetroLambda , but right now i have scenario like this as i have  describe in my question.

Comment: the example I gave above should still work for problem you described without use of RetroLambda....that just makes it look prettier :)

Comment: yeah it does , thank you, do you have some example  for Retrolambda and Rx java mix this one is bit twisted for new learner

Comment: Would recommend going through Dan Lew's series of articles - http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/15/grokking-rxjava-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

See with FlatMap Operator schoolItem your selected item

```
  api.school().flatMap(new Func1<SchoolListResponse, Observable<SchoolItem>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<SchoolItem> call(SchoolListResponse schoolListResponse) {
            return Observable.from(schoolListResponse.getSchoolList());
        }
    }).filter(new Func1<SchoolItem, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(SchoolItem schoolItem) {
            return schoolItem.getId().equals("168");
        }
    }).subscribe(new Subscriber<SchoolItem>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(SchoolItem schoolItem ) {
            //schoolItem Filtered Item
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanx for response ,for quick fix i switch to RetroLambda , Sorry could not test this one i will test this one later ,

Comment: @Drim Ok Choice is your's